# How do I upload a decoded image to imageField using ContentFile?

Tags: django, django-models

Context: I'm creating a chat app in Django, when the user sends an image to a chat the image data get encoded into base 64 (using btoa() javascript func)  and get sent to the server  so the server could create a new message and store it in the database.

This is my model:

```py
class Message(models.Model):
    sender_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to='messages/')
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    chat = models.ForeignKey(Chat, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.text
```

Problem: Whenever I use a decoded (base 64) image data as the content in the ContentFile class the content seems to be corrupted and the result image in the database can't be opened by any program.

This is the code

```py
    def create_message(
        self,
        sender_user_id: Union[str, int],
        text: str,
        image: Optional[str],
        chat_id: Union[str, int],
    ) -> None:
        """Creates and stores a new message object in the database.

        Args:
            sender_user_id (Union[str, int]): The id (numeric value) of the user that sent the message.
            text (str): What the message says.
            image (str): The encoded image data in base64 encoding.
            chat_id (Union[str, int]): The id (numeric value) of the chat that the sender sent this message on.
        """
        sender_user_instance = User.objects.get(id=sender_user_id)
        chat_instance = Chat.objects.get(id=chat_id)
        new_message = Message.objects.create(
            sender_user=sender_user_instance,
            text=text,
            date=timezone.now(),
            chat=chat_instance,
        )
        if image != "":
            image_bytes_data = base64.b64decode(image)
            # removes the prefix data:image/jpeg;base64 from the decoded bytes
            image_prefix, image_bytes = image_bytes_data.split(b",", 1)

            # print(image == base64.b64encode(image_bytes_data)) prints False
            # print(image_bytes_data == base64.b64decode(base64.b64encode(image_bytes_data))) prints True

            # Check image type
            image_type = imghdr.what(BytesIO(image_bytes_data))

            if image_type not in ["jpeg", "png", "gif"]:
                # Handle invalid image type
                print(f"Invalid image type: {image_type}")

            image_file = ContentFile(image_bytes, f"user_message.{image_type}")

            new_message.image = image_file
            new_message.save()
```

I checked the image type with the code above and it always returned me None no matter what although I tested the **image_bytes_data** value  pasting it  into a webpage base64 to image converter, the image loads without any problem and even tell me that is it a .JPEG image or .PNG.

I tried removing the prefix **data:image/jpeg;base64** from the **image_bytes_data** bytes, again, I used the webpage tool and it showed me the image but the stored image in Django can't be opened and seems corrupted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to remove the prefix `data:image/jpeg;base64,` after decoding the base64 string, which is not correct. The prefix should be removed before decoding the base64 string.

Modify your code:

```py
if image != "":
    # Split the 'data:' scheme and comma at the end of the header
    file_format, imgstr = image.split(';base64,')  
    # Get the file format (png, jpg, jpeg, etc.)
    ext = file_format.split('/')[-1]  

    # Decode the base64 image data
    data = ContentFile(base64.b64decode(imgstr), name='temp.' + ext)

    new_message.image = data
    new_message.save()
```